# Extend zeroes in a matrix

Tags: javascript

I built the Set Matrix Zeroes algorithm in JavaScript. I have a lot of loops in my code, so was wondering if there is a better way to implement this algorithm.

Given a m x n matrix, if an element is 0, set its entire row and column to 0. Do it in-place.

I loop through the matrix and when I find a 0, I set its entire row and column to a flag ('X'). I do not set 'X' if the position is a 0 because I might need to check this position in the future. At the end I replace all the 'X' to 0.

````
var setZeroes = function(matrix) {
    if(matrix === null || matrix.length === 0)
        return [];
    
    for(let i=0; i<matrix.length; i++){
        for(let j=0; j<matrix[i].length; j++){
            if(matrix[i][j] === 0){
                setFlag(matrix, i, j);
            }
        }
    }
    
    for(i=0; i<matrix.length; i++){
        for(j=0; j<matrix[i].length; j++){
            if(matrix[i][j] === 'X')
                matrix[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
};

const setFlag = function(matrix, i, j) {
    matrix[i][j] = 'X';
    let tempI = i+1;
    while(tempI < matrix.length){
        if(matrix[tempI][j] !== 0)
            matrix[tempI][j] = 'X';
        tempI++;
    }
    tempI = i-1;
    while(tempI >= 0){
        if(matrix[tempI][j] !== 0)
            matrix[tempI][j] = 'X';
        tempI--;
    }
    let tempJ = j+1;
    while(tempJ < matrix[i].length){
        if(matrix[i][tempJ] !== 0)
            matrix[i][tempJ] = 'X';
        tempJ++;
    }
    tempJ = j-1;
    while(tempJ >= 0){
        if(matrix[i][tempJ] !== 0)
            matrix[i][tempJ] = 'X';
        tempJ--;
    }
}
```
````

Answer (score 1):

From a short review;

- You probably want to encapsulate `if(matrix === null || matrix.length === 0)` into an `isValidMatrix` function for re-use
- I would drop the whole `i`/`j` thing and go for variables named after `row` and `col`
- I would collect all the rows and columns with a 0 in one set of loops, and then clear the matrix based on the collected rows and columns in another set of loops.
- `let` only declares in the block, so the `for(i=0; i<matrix.length; i++){` creates a global `i`
- I much prefer `function setFlag(matrix, i, j) {` over `const setFlag = function(matrix, i, j) {`

This is my current proposal, I did not test it, but you should get the gist of it;

```
//This does not catch everything, but it'll do
function isValidMatrix(matrix){
  return !(!matrix || !matrix.length);
}

function setZeroes(matrix) {
  
  if(!isValidMatrix(matrix))
    return [];
  
  const rows = [], cols = [];
    
  for(let row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++){
    for(let col = 0; col < matrix[row].length; col++){
      if(matrix[row][col] === 0){
        rows.push(row);
        cols.push(col);
      }
    }
  }
    
  for(let row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++){
    for(let col = 0; col < matrix[row].length; col++){
      if(rows.includes(row) || cols.includes(col)){
        matrix[row][col] = 0;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For further refinement, `rows` and `cols` might/will get multiple times the same value, so to deal with that gracefully you should use [Sets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for that.